# Need to fix the order of legend entries and the colour of components in ggplot2 line and pie charts

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, linechart

Good day all,

I am preparing pie charts and a line chart in R statistics ggplot2 and need to fix the order and colour of the legend entries and have the same colour and order for the components of the line and pie charts. I could manage to get the colours right in a previous attempt but the order went back to the default alphabetic. I have the following code to create the line chart and need to have the order as: Stem, Bark, Needle, Branch and Cone for both pie and line charts:

```r
    DRProportions$Component <- factor(DRProportions$Component, levels = c("Stem", "Bark", "Needle",    "Branch", "Cone"))

    plotly::ggplotly(
    ggplot(DRProportions, aes(x = DBH, y = Percentage, color = Component)) +
    labs(y="Percentage (%)", x="DBH (cm)")+  
    geom_line(lwd=1.1)+
    geom_point(size=2.5))
```

[image: Line Chart]

The code for the pie chart is as follow:

```r
    ggplot(DR_Model, aes(x = "", y = Percentage, fill = Component)) +
    geom_bar(width = 1, size = 1, color = "white", 
           stat = "identity") + 
    geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(Percentage), "%")),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
    coord_polar(theta = "y")+
    theme_void()+
    scale_fill_discrete(breaks=c('Stem', 'Bark', 'Needle', 'Branch', 'Cone'))
```

[image: Pie chart]

I want to have 1 decimal place for the pie charts. For the colours for both pie and line chart I would like the following: Stem=Coral1, Bark=Brown1, Needle=chartreuse, Branch=Cornsilk3 and Cone=darkgreen.

Could someone please help me with the following coding:

- Pie chart decimal to 1 decimal place;
- Line and pie chart having the same legend order and colours for the various components

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @Axeman, I am having trouble uploading more images of examples of what my data looks like, but the table for the line chart has the following headings: DBH, Component, Percentage and for the pie chart: Component, Proportion and Percentage, where the Percentage is the Proportion/100 eg. 65.3 Proportion becomes 0.653 Percentage. Hope that helps. Please let me know if I can send the data to you somehow. Thanks